# linking pdf to menu item in windows application in C#

Tags: c#

I am creating windows application in C# using Visual Studio 2010. I want to link PDF file to menu item in my menu strip.

I know how to link menu item with pdf file in web application but not in windows application, particularly with sub menu item.

Can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the item's `Click` event and call `Process.Start(pdfPath)`.
This will open the PDF in the user's default viewer.